# The set of medians is a closed interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I do not understand the following remark from the lecture:

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable. Then $m$ is a population median of $X$ if $P[X \ge m] \ge 1/2$ and $P[X \le m] \le 1/2$ holds. This is equivalent to $m$ is a minimiser of $\mathbb{E}(\vert X - v \vert)$. So far I get it, but then:
>
> The set of population median is a closed interval.

I do not see why this should this be the case. Could you explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Define $P(X \le x) = F(x)$ and $m = \sup \{y \ | \ F(y) < 1/2 \}$. Suppose that $F(m) < 1/2$, then by right-continuity, there exists $z > m$ such that $F(z) < 1/2$. A contradiction since we said that $m$ was the supremum. Hence $F(m) \ge 1/2$.

Do an analogous argument with $M = \sup \{ y \ | \ F(y) \le 1/2 \}$ to show that the closed interval $[m,M]$ is the set of medians.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on the second part of Gregory's hint, and it took me a while to work through this, since the argument is not quite the same for $M$ as it is for $m$. In case anyone else runs into the same confusion I had, here's a more detailed answer:

*Starting with Gregory's answer*:

Define $P(X \le x) = F(x)$ and $m = \sup \{y \ | \ F(y) < 1/2 \}$. Suppose that $F(m) < 1/2$, then by right-continuity, there exists $z > m$ such that $F(z) < 1/2$. A contradiction since we said that $m$ was the supremum. Hence $F(m) \ge 1/2$.

*Continuing from the second-half of the hint*:

Define $M = \sup \{ y \ | \ F(y) \le 1/2 \}$. Because $F(x)$ is nondecreasing, $F(M) \ge 1/2$.

By the definitions of $m$ and $M$, $m \le M$. If $x \in [m, M]$, $F(X) \ge 1/2$, since $F$ is nondecreasing. Also, $P(X \ge x) = 1 - F(x^-) \ge 1/2$, where $F(x^-) := \lim_{y \to x^-} F(y)$, so $F(x^-) \le 1/2$. Since $x< M$, $F(x) \le 1/2$.

If $x < m$, then $F(x) < 1/2$. If $X > M$, then F(x) > 1/2. So $[m, M]$ is the entire set of medians.